# In input text field [object Object] is shown in placeholder rather than the expected placeholder Angular

Tags: angular, input, placeholder

While working on Angular reactive forms, I'm facing an issue in giving placeholder value to text field, in placeholder [object Object] is shown rather than the expected placeholder.

```
<span *ngIf="selectedControl">
   <label>{{selectedControl.attributes.attributeName}}</label>
   <input type="{{selectedControl.attributes.type}}" [(ngModel)]="selectedControl.attributes.value">          
</span>

<div 
    class="form-group"
    *ngFor="let control of reviewForm.get('controlArray').controls; let i = index">            
    <label>{{label}} </label>                                      
    <input 
        type="{{control.value}}" 
        placeholder="selectedControl.attributes.value"                     
        class="form-control"                                                       
        [formControlName]="i"
    >                       
</div>
```

It is the object in which I store placeholder and other information.

```
{
   name:'text', attributes: {attributeName: 'Placeholder', type:'text', value:''}            
}
```

This is how I assign value to selectedControl:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedControl" class="form-control" (click)="onSelection($event)">
      <option *ngFor="let control of controlArray; let i=index" 
        [ngValue]="control">{{controlArray[i].name}}</option>                                              
</select>
```

Please help. Thanks

Comment: how does your selectedContro.attributes look like?

Comment: I edited this in my question. @Sajeetharan

Comment: how do you assign values to the selectedControl

Comment: using two way data binding

Comment: show the code where you assign the value

Comment: Edited this in my question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157120/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-waleed-shahzaib).

Comment: selectedControl.attributes.attributesName